# How to test whether a file uses CRLF or LF without modifying it?

Tags: bash, text-processing, newlines

I need to periodically run a command that ensures that some *text* files are kept in Linux mode. Unfortunately `dos2unix` always modifies the file, which would mess file's and folder's timestamps and cause unnecessary writes.

The script I write is in Bash, so  I'd prefer answers based on Bash.

Answer (score 96):

**Note: This should not be used in automation scripts, just for checking quickly. For automation scripts, I'd suggest you look at other answers**

Use `cat -A`

```
$ cat file
hello
hello
```

Now if this file was made in *NIX systems, it would display

```
$ cat -A file
hello$
hello$
```

But if this file was made in Windows, it would display

```
$ cat -A file
hello^M$
hello
```

`^M` represents `CR` and `$` represents `LF`.

I used Windows Notepad in Windows and Vim in Linux.
Notice that Windows Notepad did not save the last line with `CRLF`.

This does not change the file contents either.

Comment: +1 By far the best answer. No dependencies, no complicated bash scripts. Just `-A` to cat. One tip though would be to use `cat -A file | less` if the file is too big. I'm sure it's not uncommon to have to check file endings for a particularly long file. (Press `q` to leave less)

Comment: I think `cat -ve` can be used as well and is more portable.

Comment: If you use Rust's version of `cat` (`bat`), then it's even more clear visually.

Comment: Thanks, @Oskar, indeed `cat -A` did not work on macOS but `cat -ve` was fine.

Comment: If anybody has bat (https://github.com/sharkdp/bat, handy `cat`/`less` replacement to have anyway) then `bat -A myfile` actually make  this very nice to read, by displaying formatted `␍` and `␊` as applicable

Answer (score 59):

You can use `dos2unix` as a filter and compare its output to the original file:

```
dos2unix < myfile.txt | cmp - myfile.txt
```

Comment: Very smart and useful, because it tests **the complete file** and not only the first or a few line.

Answer (score 32):

If the goal is just to avoid affecting the timestamp, `dos2unix` has a `-k` or `--keepdate` option which will keep the timestamp the same. It will still have to do a write to make the temporary file and rename it, but your timestamps will not be affected.

If any modification of the file is unacceptable, you can use the following solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73969/2345242).

```
find . -not -type d -exec file "{}" ";" | grep CRLF
```

The `file` command will output `CRLF` if it detects such line terminations.

Comment: Do you mean you literally write CRLF as 4 characters C, R, L and F?

Comment: Do you also mean that grep can take CR and LF just like that?

Comment: @bodacydo It's explained in the answer he links to, and now also in Scott's edit of BertS' answer here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79708/59699 .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I dont see explanation. It only mentions CRLF but doesnt explain what it is.

Comment: @bodacydo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-on-linu/73969#73969 
says that `find ... -exec file ... | grep CRLF` for a file with DOS line endings (i.e. bytes 0D 0A) "will get you something like: `./1/dos1.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` 
As you can see this contains the actual string CRLF and therefore is matched by `grep` looking for the simple string CRLF.

Comment: @bodacydo http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79702/how-to-test-whether-a-file-uses-crlf-or-lf-without-modifying-it/79708#79708 
(considering only a file containing 0D 0A line endings) says that "`file` reports something like:
`myfile.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`". That answer checks using shell `[[` 
rather than `grep` but for matching a plain string like CRLF those work the same.

Comment: This solution isn't very complete, it will miss a lot of text files. Because `file` doesn't report line endings on all types of text files. For example, for json files it just says `JSON data` and for svg files it says `SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image`. In both cases it does not include any information about line endings.

Answer (score 30):

Since version `7.1` dos2unix has an `-i`, `--info` option to get information about line breaks. You can use dos2unix itself to test which files need conversion.

For example, assuming GNU `xargs` and that none of your file names contain newline characters:

```
dos2unix -ic -- *.txt | xargs -rd '\n' dos2unix --
```

Would only convert the files that need converting (reported as such by `dos2unix -ic`).

Comment: Here is link to the changelog itself http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix/NEWS.txt

Comment: The fields output by that flag have no headers, but they are: number of DOS line breaks, number of Unix line breaks, number of Mac line breaks, byte order mark, text or binary, file name. So if the first column is nonzero then you have some DOS linebreaks.

Answer (score 28):

You could try to `grep` for CRLF code, octal:

```
grep -U $'\015' myfile.txt
```

or hex:

```
grep -U $'\x0D' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Of course, the assumption is that this is a text file.

Comment: I like this `grep` usage because it allows me to easily list all such files in the directory with `grep -lU $'\x0D' *` and pass the output to `xargs`.

Comment: whats the meaning of the $ before the search pattern? @don_crissti

Comment: @fersarr - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401451/22142

Comment: This only tests for a CR, not necessarily a CR-LF sequence.

Comment: If there is binary files but I want to test text files only, grep gets too much outputs.

Answer (score 21):

#### First method (`grep`):

Count the lines that contain a carriage return:

```
[[ $(grep -c $'\r' myfile.txt) -gt 0 ]] && echo dos
```

Count the lines that *end with* a carriage return:

```
[[ $(grep -c $'\r$' myfile.txt) -gt 0 ]] && echo dos
```

These will typically be equivalent;
a carriage return in the interior of a line (i.e., not at the end) is rare.

More efficient:

```
grep -q $'\r' myfile.txt && echo dos
```

This is more efficient

1. because it doesn't need to convert the count to an ASCII string,
   and then convert that string back to an integer, and compare it to zero, and
2. because `grep -c` needs to read the entire file,
   to count all the occurrences of the pattern,
   while `grep -q` can exit upon seeing the first occurrence of the pattern.

**Notes:**

- Throughout the above, you may need to add the `-U` option
  (i.e., use `-cU` or `-qU`),
  because GNU `grep` guesses whether the file is a text file. 
  If it thinks the file is text, it ignores carriage returns at the ends of lines,
  in an attempt to make **`$`** in regular expressions work "correctly" —
  even if the regular expression is **`\r$`**! 
  Specifying `-U` (or `--binary`) overrules this guesswork,
  causing `grep` to treat the file(s) as binary
  and pass the data to the matching mechanism verbatim, with CR-endings intact.
- Do not do `grep … $'\r\n' myfile.txt`,
  because `grep` treats `\n` as a pattern delimiter. 
  Just as `grep -E 'foo|'` looks for lines containing `foo` or a null string,
  `grep $'\r\n'` looks for lines containing `\r` or a null string,
  and every line matches a null string.

#### Second method (`file`):

```
[[ $(file myfile.txt) =~ CRLF ]] && echo dos
```

because `file` reports something like:

```
myfile.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Safer variant:

```
[[ $(file -b - < myfile.txt) =~ CRLF ]] && echo dos
```

where

- `file -b` outputs only the file type, and not the file name. 
  Without this, a file *whose **name** included the characters `CRLF`*
  would trigger a false positive.
- `file - < filename` works
  even if *`filename`* begins with **`-`**. 
  <sup>See [Bash script: check if a file is a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208942/23408).</sup>

Beware that checking the output from `file`
might not work in a non-English locale.

Comment: You can replace `"$(echo -e '\r')"` with the much simpler `$'\r'`, although personally I'd use `$'\r\n'` to reduce the number of false positives.

Comment: @rici `grep $'\r\n'` seems to match all files on my system...

Comment: @rici: good catch. I edited my answer according to your suggestion. — depquid: Maybe you are on Windows? :-) rici's tip works here.

Comment: @depquid (and BertS): Actually, I think the correct invocation is `grep -U $'\r$'`, to prevent `grep` trying to second-guess line-endings.

Comment: Also, you can use `-q` to just set the return code if a match is found, instead of `-c` which requires an additional check. Personally I like your second solution, although it's highly dependent on the whims of `file` and might not work in a non-English locale.

Comment: @BertS Nope, Fedora 17.  Works on an old Ubuntu 8.04 system, though.

Comment: @BertS: yep. `\n` acts as a pattern delimiter, so it's effectively ignored in patterns. It definitely should have been `$'\r$'`. But the matching every file behaviour is still a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: Hi When you write `CRLF` do you mean literally CRLF as 4 ASCII characters C, R, L and F?

Comment: @bodacydo: Do you understand it yet?  Would you understand it better if the answer said something like `[[ $(file -b - < myfile.txt) =~ "with CRLF line terminators" ]]`?

Answer (score 9):

Use `file`:

```
$ file README.md
README.md: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

$ dos2unix README.md
dos2unix: converting file README.md to Unix format...

$ file README.md
README.md: ASCII text
```

Comment: This idea has been discussed much more thoroughly in two previous answers.

Comment: You can use the -k switch in file command to check the complete file. Heres the excerpt from help `-k, --keep-going           don't stop at the first match`

Answer (score 7):

a bash function for you:

```
# return 0 (true) if first line ends in CR
isDosFile() {
    [[ $(head -1 "$1") == *$'\r' ]]  
}
```

Then you can do stuff like

```
streamFile () {
    if isDosFile /tmp/foo.txt; then
        sed 's/\r$//' "$1"
    else
        cat "$1"
    fi
}

streamFile /tmp/foo.txt | process_lines_without_CR
```

Comment: You don't have to use `isDosFile()` in your example: `streamFile() { sed 's/\r$//' "$1" ; }`.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution; it doesn't read whole file, just the first line.

Answer (score 5):

If a file has DOS/Windows-style CR-LF line endings, then if you look at it using a Unix-based tool you'll see CR ('\r') characters at the end of each line.

This command:

```
grep -l '^M$' filename
```

will print `filename` if the file contains one or more lines with Windows-style line endings, and will print nothing if it doesn't. Except that the `^M` has to be a literal carriage return character, typically entered in the terminal by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
(or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>). The bash shell lets you write a literal carriage return as `$'\r'` ([documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)), so you can write:

```
grep -l $'\r$' filename
```

Other shells may provide a similar feature.

You can use another tool instead:

```
awk '/\r$/ { exit(1) }' filename
```

This will exit with a status of `1` (setting `$?` to `1`) if the file contains any Windows-style line endings, and with a status of `0` if it doesn't, making it useful in a shell `if` statement (note the lack of `[` brackets `]`):

```
if awk '/\r$/ { exit(1) }' filename ; then
    echo filename has Unix-style line endings
else
    echo filename has at least one Windows-style line ending
fi
```

A file can contain a mixture of Unix-style and Windows-style line endings. I'm assuming here that you want to detect files that have *any* Windows-style line endings.

Comment: You can encode a carriage return on the command line in bash (and some other shells) by typing `$'\r'`, as mentioned in other answers to this question.

Comment: +1 for insisting that the CR must immediately precede the LF to qualify as a CR-LF.  Also, note that `grep -q $'\r''$' filename` is equally useful in `if` statements, although the test polarity is reversed from your `awk` example.  `if grep -q $'\r''$' filename ; then echo DOS-style; else echo UNIX-style; fi`

Answer (score 3):

I have been using

```
cat -v filename.txt | diff - filename.txt
```

which seems to work. I find the output a little easier to read than

```
dos2unix < filename.txt | diff - filename.txt
```

It is also useful if you can't install `dos2unix` for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

`file` tells you the line endings, but *only if they are not Unix-style*:

```
❯ echo "hello1\nhello2\n" > hello-unix.txt
❯ cp hello-unix.txt hello-dos.txt
❯ cp hello-unix.txt hello-mac.txt
❯ unix2dos hello-dos.txt
unix2dos: converting file hello-dos.txt to DOS format...
❯ unix2mac hello-mac.txt
unix2mac: converting file hello-mac.txt to Mac format...
❯ file hello-unix.txt
hello-unix.txt: ASCII text
❯ file hello-dos.txt
hello-dos.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
❯ file hello-mac.txt
hello-mac.txt: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

So:

- If `file` reports "CRLF line terminators", the file is DOS-style
- If `file` reports "CR line terminators", the file is Mac-style
- If `file` doesn't mention line terminators, the file is Unix-style

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer to the original question.