# Bash script: check if a file is a text file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, file-command

I am writing a menu based bash script, one of the menu options is to send an email with a text file attachment. I am having trouble with checking if my file is a text file. Here is what I have:

```
fileExists=10
until [ $fileExists -eq 9 ]
do
  echo "Please enter the name of the file you want to attach: "
  read attachment
  isFile=$(file $attachment | cut -d\ -f2)
  if [[ $isFile = "ASCII" ]]
    then
      fileExists=0
    else
      echo "$attachment is not a text file, please use a different file"
  fi
done
```

I keep getting the error cut: delimiter must be a single character.

Comment: Put an extra space after `-d\ `.

Comment: Depending on the `file` version you have available you should consider using some options like `--brief` (which doesn't output the filename so you will have less of a problem with filenames that contain spaces) or `--mime` which returns the MIME type (e.g. `text/plain`) instead of a textual description of the file type.

Comment: Just a note on the off-topic closure - This question would still help a lot of future readers like me. I was looking for an if statement to check if a file contained text, and this one helped me perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs in `cut -d\ -f2`. Change it to `cut -d\  -f2`.

To `cut`, the arguments look like this:

```
# bash: args(){ for i; do printf '%q \\\n' "$i"; done; }
# args cut -d\ -f2
cut \
-d\ -f2 \
```

And here is the problem. `\` escaped the space to a space literal instead of a delimiter between arguments in your shell, and you didn't add an extra space so the whole `-d\ -f2` part appears as one argument. You should add one extra space so `-d\`  and `-f2` appear as two arguments.

To avoid confusion, many people use quotes like `-d' '` instead.

P.S.: Instead of using file and making everything ASCII, I'd rather use

```
if file "$attachment2" | grep -q text$; then
    # is text
else
    # file doesn't think it's text
fi
```

Comment: ah thank you! It was my spaces again, but it's working now!

Comment: @Powea Added an alternative.

Answer (score 7):

1. From the fact that it says `file $attachment`
   rather than `file "$attachment"`,
   I guess your script cannot handle filenames that contain spaces. 
   But, be advised that filenames can contain spaces,
   and well-written scripts can handle them.  Note, then:

   ```
   $ file "foo bar"
   foo bar:  ASCII text

   $ file "foo bar" | cut -d' ' -f2
   bar:
   ```

   One popular and highly recommended approach
   is to null-terminate the filenames:

   ```
   $ file -0 "foo bar" | cut -d $'\0' -f2
   :  ASCII text
   ```
2. The `file` command makes educated guesses about
   what type of file a file is.  Guesses, naturally, are sometime wrong. 
   For example, `file` will sometimes look at an ordinary text file
   and guess that it is a shell script, C program, or something else. 
   So you don't want to check whether the output from `file` *is* `ASCII text`,
   you want to see whether it *says* that the file is a text file. 
   If you look at the man page for `file`,
   you will see that it more-or-less promises
   to include the word `text` in its output if the file is a text file,
   but this might be in a context like `shell commands text`. 
   So, it may be better to check whether the output from `file`
   contains the word `text`:

   ```
   isFile=$(file -0 "$attachment" | cut -d $'\0' -f2)
   case "$isFile" in
      (*text*)
         echo "$attachment is a text file"
         ;;
      (*)
         echo "$attachment is not a text file, please use a different file"
         ;;
   esac
   ```

Comment: You cannot rely on substrings in the output of `file` as for many formats `file` extracts and displays strings from the file (look for `%s` in the magic sources) which may include `text`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Perhaps you should take the wisdom that you have sprinkled over this page (`-b`, `< ` *`filename`*, `--mime`) and add it to your answer, rather than scribbling it on leaves and letting them blow into everybody else’s yards.  :-)  ⁠

Answer (score 6):

```sh
case $(file -b --mime-type - < "$attachment") in
  (text/*)
     printf '%s\n' "$attachment is probably text according to file"
     case $(file -b --mime-encoding - < "$attachment") in
       (us-ascii) echo "and probably in ASCII encoding"
     esac
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

I would circumvent the escaping and do:

```
... | cut -d' ' -f2
```

that way it is clear that you need a space between the delimiter character (specified by the three letters sequence `' '`) and the following option. With `-d\ -f2` it is easy to miss you should have done `-d\  -f2`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to not use `cut` and to match a regex against the full output of `file`:

```
#...
isFile=$(file $attachment)
if [[ "$var" =~ ^[^:]*:\ ASCII ]]
#...
```

Comment: The elephant in the room is that the output from `file` is of the form “(filename) (colon) (whitespace) (filetype)” — i.e., it includes the filename.  Therefore, if there is a binary file called `VACASCIING.JPG`, the output from `file` will be `VACASCIING.JPG:  JPEG image`, and your code will call it a text file because the *filename* matches `ASCII`.  Note that the second part of [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208972/80216), which is functionally comparable to yours,   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  would not have needed the `cut` command but for this.  (The OP is using `cut` to extract the first word of the filetype, which he tests for equality.  I’m doing a pattern match, like you, so I could have just used the entire output, but I use `cut` to get the filetype only, without the filename.)  Also, [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208980/80216) uses `file < "$attachment"`, and, while not explained, I presume that that trick is also intended to get output without the filename.

Comment: @G-Man Indeed that was a pretty big elephant. Thanks for your comment. I've updated making the regex way more consistent.

Comment: @G-Man, no `-b` avoids printing the filename. Using `<` is to avoid problems with a file called `-`.

Comment: @kos, now you're moving the problem to files with `:` in their name.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're right. I'm coming from Windows and I always forget about this. Either I'll work out a solution to make this work consistently or I'll delete this answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Wow; I keep on learning things from you.  Thanks².  But I guess any filename *beginning* with `-` would be a problem.  And it looks like you could have used `file -- "$attachment"`, although it’s not mentioned in the man page.

Comment: @G-Man,  I used `file - < "$attachment"`. `file -` tries to identify the file content of stdin. so it's simliar to `file -sL -- "$attachment"` except that it also work for a file called `-` (`--` doesn't help with that).

Comment: @G-Man - i think the simple solution to the filename thing is simply to cancel by compariso . It can't that much of a hurdle if we already have all of the pertinent values in named vars at our disposal. Just: `printf 'file reports type:\t%s\n' "${var#*"$attachment"*:}"`