# bash: ls -l with grep

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, find

I have this:

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep ASCII
```

This is the output:

[image: That's is what is print in terminal.]

I want to know if is possible to show the size of the files and their path, for all files that `file` indicates as `ASCII`.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do? You have told us what you have tried (this is good), and what happened (also good, though why a picture (not self contained on this site) of text, this is a waste of bandwidth and storage, but more importantly it makes if harder to copy (this is sometimes needed if someone needs to experiment to find an answer), and harder for blind people to read.) Please amend question to address these issues.

Comment: The command `wc(1)` gives characters/words/lines for text files. `ls(1)` gives the size of files with `-l`.

Comment: Related: [Bash script: check if a file is a text file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208942/80216).

Answer (score 4):

This uses cut to extract the filename from the output of `file | grep ASCII`, and then pipes it into `xargs stat -c ...` to display only filename and size:

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep  ASCII | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -d'\n' -r stat -c '%n %s'
```

If you want the size before the filename, use `'%s %n'` in the `stat` command.

It will cope with filenames that contain any character except `:` or newline. It assumes a GNU system (for `-d` and that `stat` syntax). It could give false positives if `ASCII` is present in the file path.

Comment: @JoséSá If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a shell loop instead. If you are using `bash`, you can make `**` recurse into subdirectories by running `shopt -s globstar`. As explained in `man bash`:

```
globstar
    If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion con‐
    text will match all files and zero or  more  directories
    and  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /,
    only directories and subdirectories match.
```

So, with that in mind, you could use the following loop:

```
shopt -s globstar 
for file in **; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && file "$file" | grep -q "ASCII" && stat -c '%n %s' "$file"
done
```

Comment: that for only show me the files in the directory and not the other in the subdirectories

Comment: @JoséSá it will if you run `shopt -s globstar` first. That's what I explain in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```sh
isascii() [[ $(file -b --mime-encoding - < ${1-$REPLY}) = us-ascii ]]
zmodload zsh/stat
zstat -n +size -- **/*(D.L+1+isascii)
```

Broken down:

- `**/*` recursive globbing, [a feature introduced by zsh in the early 90s and later copied by some other shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665) like `ksh93`, `fish`, `bash`, `yash` and `tcsh`.
- `(...)`, *glob qualifier*: another 90s feature but still unique to `zsh` as of today. Allows to further specify which files are included in the glob based on file metadata or to change the expanded value. Here:

  - `D`: include **D**ot (hidden) files
  - `.`: include only regular files
  - `L+1`: only bother considering files that are more than 1 byte large (as otherwise `file` won't tell you anything about them)
  - `+isascii`: calls the `isascii` command for each matching file to decide whether to include the file.
- `isascii` is defined as a function that calls `file` on `$REPLY` (that's how file names are passed for functions called by glob qualifiers, functions may modify it or return more files in the `$reply` array). We use `${1-$REPLY}` here so we can also use that function on a file given as argument, and don't modify `$REPLY`, just return the decision via the exit status.

  With `-b` and `--mime-encoding`, `file` (at least the implementation from `libmagic`) outputs only the guessed encoding. It's a lot more reliable than calling `grep ASCII` on the output of `file the-file`,
  as `ASCII` may occur there in the file path or other information extracted from the file.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit for the zsh-challenged?

Comment: @terdon, see edit

Comment: You forgot to do `file … ` **`- < `** *`filename`* (which I learned from you).  :-)  ⁠

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

for file_name in `find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep ASCII | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`; do  ls -lrth ${file_name}; done