# Filter files generated by `find` by parsed output of `file` command

Tags: shell, awk, find

I'm writing a quick tool to inspect the contents of a node.js `node_modules` folder or python `virtualenv` for native dependencies. As a quick first approximation to this I wrote the following command.

```
find . | xargs file | awk '/C source/ {print $1} /ELF/ {print $1}'
```

I'm okay with false positives but not false negatives (e.g. files literally containing the string `ELF` or `C source` can be marked suspicious.), but this script also potentially breaks on long file names (because `xargs` will split them) and file names containing spaces (because awk will split on whitespace) and file names containing newlines (because find uses newlines to separate paths).

Is there a way to filter the paths generated by `find` by seeing if the output of `file {}` (possibly with some additional options to remove the path entirely from the output of `file`) matches a particular regular expression?

Comment: Use -exec cmd {} + instead of the nonstandard -print0.

Comment: Your updated command looks better, but it is still susceptible to filenames with spaces or newlines. If you can get the list of files from `find` and iterate F over that list, then you can `echo "$F"` whenever the output of `file $F | grep ...` returns success.

Comment: OP - get rid of the pipe and do it `find` only; use `file` with `-b` so as to use `grep` with anchor e.g. `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b "$0" | grep -q "^ELF\|^C source" && printf %s\\n "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: @don_crissti , excellent !! It solves all problems given by OP, and should be the answer here. Key point is that `-exec file` is not enough, but `-exec sh ...` allows a whole small script to be executed for each file, with `find` itself doing the iteration !!

Comment: @don_crissti Why does the `{}` argument to the inner script become `$0` instead of `$1` in the body of the script? `sh -c "echo $0" hi`, for instance, prints `/bin/bash` on my machine.

Comment: Visit [this page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202974); also follow the links there...

Comment: @don_crissti Done. Perhaps this is more appropriate as a meta question, but a) you came up with the solution and b) the `find -exec file {} +` ... solution is still better than what I originally posted, but doesn't directly address the whitespace problem. What's the right thing to do in terms of packaging that as an answer?

Comment: More generally, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: @don_crissti, if the only desired output is a human-readable list of filenames, there will never be a *fully unambiguous* way to distinguish them later, although the fact that every path reported by `find` will contain at least one slash will definitely help.  But see [my answer below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274803/135943); you can easily modify the `-print` flag in the first command to another `-exec` operator and thereby handle any special character filenames safely for whatever you need to do.

Comment: Also relevant: [Bash script: check if a file is a text file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208942/80216). Suggestion: read everything Stéphane Chazelas wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key factor in reaching `find` enlightenment ;) is:

> `find`'s business is evaluating expressions -- not locating files. Yes, `find` certainly locates files; but that's really just a side effect.
>
> [*--Unix Power Tools*](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch09_12.htm)

There is an alternate approach to this question that it's worth knowing about (as also described in Unix Power Tools, in the section ["Using -exec to Create Custom Tests"](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch09_10.htm)):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b "$1" | grep -iqE "^ELF|^C source"' sh {} \; -print
```

It's worth knowing about this filtering method since it can be used for many more things than simply printing the name of the file; just change the `-print` operator to any other operator you like (including another `-exec` operator) and do what you like with it.

---

There *is* a performance drawback to this command (which is also present in [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274779/135943)), which is that since we are using `\;` and not `+`, we are spawning a shell for every single file.  Using `+` to pass multiple files at once to the `sh` command and processing them with a `for` loop gives a noticeable performance advantage:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'for f do file -b "$f" | grep -qE "^ELF|^C source" && printf %s\\n "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

You can see the comparison for yourself by running both of the following commands and comparing the output of `time`:

```
time find . -exec sh -c 'for f do file -b "$f" | grep -qE "^ELF|^C source" && printf %s\\n "$f"; done' sh {} +
time find . -exec sh -c 'file -b "$1" | grep -qE "^ELF|^C source" && printf %s\\n "$1"' sh {} \;
```

---

The real point, though, is:

**Never run a shell `for` loop on a list of files that is output from `find`.**  Instead, either run the action you need to do on each file directly within `find` by using the `-exec` operator, or *embed* a shell `for` loop *within* a `find` command and do it that way.

Some additional reasons:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: Does `+` in place of `\;` affect the character used to separate lines of output from find or whether a subprocess is spawned for each invocation?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, the latter—see [POSIX specs for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (or just look at `man find`).  `+` affects the behavior of the `-exec` operator and makes `find` run whatever command is specified after `-exec` with *multiple* files as arguments, rather than just one.  Actually, I just realized your answer has no performance benefit as written; I will update my answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I'm trying to find how `for f; do` is nonstandard and from the line about `for_clause` on [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) it seems it should be standard...`sequential_sep` can be a `;`, right?  I'm not sure I've got the hang of the grammar depiction format, though....

Comment: See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=581

Comment: So, with the 2016 edition now released, that's no longer true, I'll remove my comment. (you still need `for f do` for the Bourne shell though).

Comment: Excuse the simplistic question. How do I then take this list of files and use them as input to a binary in the most efficient way? I tried a pipe `|` at the end but that didn't work.

Comment: @frakman1 see examples in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/135943 that have "somecommand" or "somecommandwith" in them.  If that's not enough, please post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

It is easiest to execute a small script for every file that checks the brief-mode output of `file` and prints the path if the output of `file` matches `ELF` or `C source`, the path is passed in as `$0`.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c \
    'file -b "$0" | grep -q "^ELF\|^C source" && printf %s\\n "$0"' {} \;
```

This solution has the following advantages over the original

`-type f` filters out directories immediately instead of relying on the output of `file`

Passing in the argument as `{}` avoids issues related to whitespace or newlines in the file name.