# What Does Regex $'s/\r$//' do?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Todd Schneider uses the following command in his [NYC Taxi Data Analysis](https://github.com/toddwschneider/nyc-taxi-data) to prep a CSV file for PostresSQL.

```
sed $'s/\r$//' $filename | sed '/^$/d' | ...
```

The second sed command removes blank lines.  What does the first one do?

Comment: he tries to remove carriage return char `\r` at the end of the line. Looks doubtful, I see the most windows files with `CRLF` at the end (not single `CR`)

Comment: Not doubtful. The trailing newline, being the line terminator, will not be present in the current line as seen by sed. Hence, the last character on the line is `\r`. If the file contained CR line endings, sed would see the whole file as a single line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to `man bash`:

> ```
>   Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to
>    string,  with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
>    ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present,  are  decoded
>    as follows:                                      
>           \a     alert (bell)                       
>           \b     backspace                          
>           \e                                        
>           \E     an escape character                
>           \f     form feed                          
>           \n     new line                           
>           \r     carriage return                    
>           \t     horizontal tab                     
>           \v     vertical tab                       
>           \\     backslash                          
>           \'     single quote                       
>           \"     double quote                       
>           \?     question mark                      
>           \nnn   the  eight-bit  character  whose value is the octal value
>                  nnn (one to three digits)          
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value  is  the  hexadecimal
>                  value HH (one or two hex digits)   
>           \uHHHH the  Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the
>                  hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>           \UHHHHHHHH                                
>                  the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is  the
>                  hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
>           \cx    a control-x character              
>   The  expanded  result  is  single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not
>    been present.
> ```

Consequently `$'s/\r$//'` deletes an ASCII `CR` at end of line.  It's a crude way to convert Windows line endings to UNIX line endings.

Comment: Ahh great.  My plan is to analyze this in Windows so I shouldn't need to do this modification.

Comment: Then you need a Windows-specific version of `sed` (and other similar utilities).  Plain translations such as Cygwin won't work.