# Move specific files to another folder based on partial pattern in .txt file

Tags: mv, for

I have a folder with various file types, but I am interested in the files with `.img` as extension, with the following pattern:

```
ppi_noTD_d0_P_76con_0001.img
ppi_noTD_d0_P_104con_0001.img
ppi_noTD_d0_P_150con_0001.img
ppi_noTD_d0_P_201con_0001.img
etc.
```

The only changing bit of the file names is the `P_XXX` part.

I have created two .txt files, `stable.txt` and `recurring.txt`, each containing a list of a subset of `P_XXX` that I would like to use to move the subsets to separate folders (*stable* and *recurring*, respectively). For example, `P_76` and `P_201` are listed in *stable.txt*, while `P_104` and `P_154` are listed in *recurring.txt*.

I tried a `for loop` to return the relevant `P_XXX` from the .txt file, so that I can use that to retrieve the matching `.img` in another `for loop` from the folder, which should then be moved to the *stable* folder:

```
for P in $(< stable.txt); do
     for f in *"$P"*.img; do
         echo mv - "$f" "./stable/$f"
     done
done
```

It returns the correct number of `P_XXX` listed, but `$f` does not return the full filename (only the `*P_XXX` bit). Strangely enough, it does return the full filename for the last `P_XXX` in the .txt file (so `ppi_noTD_d0_P_201_con_0001.img`)

As there seems to be something going wrong with calling `$f`, I can't move the files to their respective folders (*stable* and *recurring*).

How do I solve this?

---

EDIT:

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
*.img ./stable/*P_76
*.img ./stable/*P_86
*.img ./stable/*P_89
*.img ./stable/*P_90
*.img ./stable/*P_91
*.img ./stable/*P_99
*.img ./stable/*P_121
*.img ./stable/*P_128
*.img ./stable/*P_132
*.img ./stable/*P_136
*.img ./stable/*P_140
*.img ./stable/*P_144
*.img ./stable/*P_153
*.img ./stable/*P_156
*.img ./stable/*P_162
*.img ./stable/*P_180
*.img ./stable/*P_203
*.img ./stable/*P_205
*.img ./stable/*P_208
*.img ./stable/*P_211
*.img ./stable/*P_215
*.img ./stable/*P_229
*.img ./stable/*P_250
*.img ./stable/*P_256
mv - ppi_noTD_d0_P_257con_0001.img ./stable/ppi_noTD_d0_P_257con_0001.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stable.txt` file was likely created or edited on a Windows system, where the [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is represented by the carriage rturn + line feed sequence (often referred to using the abbreviation `CR` `LF` or the escape sequence `\r\n`).

For instance, assuming this sample file:

```
printf '%s\r\n' P_76 P_201 >stable.txt
```

After the first line is read by your script, the globbing expression `*"$P"*.img` matches nothing (unless your file names actually contain carriage return characters) and, if no `nullglob` (or equivalent) option is in effect, the value of `f` is `*P_76\r*.img`. When `mv - "$f" "./stable/$f"` is echoed, the two `CR` characters cause the subsequent text to be inserted at the beginning of the line, overwriting what was already there.

You can check your files for `CR` `LF` newline sequences with

```
$ cat -v stable.txt
P_76^M
P_201^M
```

or

```
$ od -An -c stable.txt
   P   _   7   6  \r  \n   P   _   2   0   1  \r  \n
```

or

```sh
$ file stable.txt
stable.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

And you can convert them to the Unix, LF-terminated format with (among other ways):

```sh
$ dos2unix stable.txt
```

#### See also:

- [How to test whether a file uses CRLF or LF without modifying it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79702/315749)