# how to remove non-standard end of line characters in bash?

Tags: linux, pipe, character-encoding

Sometimes, when passing the name of files from a config.txt into a pipe, I get weird problems of non-existing files. I fear it is due to some non-standard end of line characters. I am using kate as standard IDE, the end of line should simply be \n.

How can I remove the unwanted characters and assure that each line terminates with \n using bash?

Thank you

Comment: What characters?  If the character isn't one of `\r` or `\n`, it's not an end-of-line character any more than `X` or `4`  is an end-of-line character.

Comment: Do you have a file that will reproduce the problem? Then please [edit] your question and show both the content of the file and output of `od -c your_file`

Comment: You might find help in [How to test whether a file uses CRLF or LF without modifying it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79702/315749) and [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/315749). Chances are your question turned out to be a duplicate of the latter.

Comment: the ^M is probably the problem, even if I don't use windows and I can't see any strange character. But if I switch from Kate to Gedit, the error disappeared. Tx

Answer (score 1):

try `dos2unix` or `d2u`. If this does not work, then you will have to tell us more about what the characters are.