# How to not interpret string as command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing a script which should copy a client system and change some lines in a file.

There is a source file which has a line like:

```
$DB_HOST = "LegitDbHost";
```

And the destination file has a line like:

```
$DB_HOST = "testDbHost";
```

So i need to replace the destination line with the source line and I want to print out something like this:

```
Replacing line 12: '$DB_HOST = "testDbHost";' ==with==> '$DB_HOST = "LegitDbHost";'(y/n):
```

So far i got this:

```
toReplace='$DB_HOST';

sourceLine=$(cat ./sourceFile.php | grep -m 1 "$toReplace[[:space:],=]");
destLineNr=$(cat ./destFile.php | grep -n -m 1 "$toReplace[[:space:],=]" | grep -Eo '^[^:]+');
destLine=$(cat ./destFile.php | grep -m 1 "$toReplace[[:space:],=]");
read -p "Replacing line $destLineNr: $destLine ==with==> $sourceLine.(y/n): ";
```

however, my output looks like this:

```
==with==> $DB_HOST    ST   = "testDbHost";.(y/n):
```

I think it's because the sourceLine has a `;` inside and that gets interpreted as a command end.
I just don't know how to get around that.

I hope it's understandable.

**Edit:**
as suggested i tried using `echo -n`

```
toReplace='$DB_HOST';

sourceLine=$(cat ./sourceFile.php | grep -m 1 "$toReplace[[:space:],=]");
destLineNr=$(cat ./destFile.php | grep -n -m 1 "$toReplace[[:space:],=]" | grep -Eo '^[^:]+');
destLine=$(cat ./destFile.php | grep -m 1 "$toReplace[[:space:],=]");

echo -n "Replacing line $destLineNr: "
echo -n $destLine
echo -n " ===with===> "
echo -n $sourceLine
```

this prints out:

```
===with===> $DB_HOST = "testDbHost";OS";
```

Comment: It sounds more like your problem has to do with your files having Microsoft DOS/Windows CRLF line delimiters. You may want to run `dos2unix` on them first.

Comment: Why not just echo your string with the variable substitutions (optionally with the `-n` flag to prevent a terminal newline being appended) and then call `read -p '(y/n)?'` as the next command in the script? That should accomplish what you desire, if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: tried echo -n. See my edit. Also tried dos2unix, but it's not installed on the system and I don't have permissions to do so.

Comment: To check whether it is as @StéphaneChazelas says use `hd` or `od` to just dump a specific line and show output. eg. `grep DB_HOST sourceFile.php|hd` repeat with destFile.php if you haven't got `hd` use `od -cbx --endian big` (btw, your code works for me using bash)

Comment: On detecting and removing carriage return characters: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79702/315749 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/315749

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
die() {
  print -ru2 -- "$@"
  exit 1
}

srcFile=./sourceFile.php
dstFile=./destFile.php

toReplace='$DB_HOST'

sourceLine=$(<"$srcFile" grep -Pm1 "\Q$toReplace\E[\s,=]") ||
  die "Can't find $toReplace in $srcFile"

<"$dstFile" grep -nPm 1 "\Q$toReplace\W[\s,=]" |
  IFS=: read -r destLineNr destLine ||
  die "Can't find $toReplace in $dstFile"

if
  read -q "?Replacing line $destLineNr: ${(q+)destLine} ==with==> ${(q+)sourceLine}? (y/n): "
then
  (
     export destLineNr destLine
     perl -lpi -e '$_ = $ENV{destLine} if $. == $ENV{destLineNr}' -- "$dstFile"
  )
fi
```

Using `${(q+)line}` zsh parameter expansion, will make sure CR characters in that variable (as it looks like your input files have MSDOS CRLF delimiters instead of Unix LF ones) is rendered as `C-M` instead of being sent as-is to the terminal (for a terminal, a CR character makes the cursor go back to the beginning of the line (makes the carriage return for teletypewriter ones)).

Comment: getting this now: 
Warning: unknown mime-type for "-ru2" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "-ru2"
Error: no such file "Can't find $DB_HOST in ./destFile.php"

Comment: i have to mention that I'm a total beginner in terms of bash scripting. I got this task from my company, just started to google some commands yesterday.

Comment: @Pascal, that's a zsh script not a bash script (note the shebang). Either make it executable with `chmod a+x that-script` and run it as `./that-script` or run it as `zsh ./that-script`, not `bash ./that-script`.

Comment: tried. it says: -bash: zsh: command not found