# Bash Script : Problem with variables from csv file

Tags: bash, shell-script, csv, ksh, variable-substitution

I'm having a little problem getting variables from a csv file on my Linux machine and using them in an `if`. I have the following csv:

```
Name;Age
Marc;18
Joseph;10
```

I'm trying to get this information from my csv to use in a function:

My bash code :

```
#!/bin/ksh

while IFS=";" read -r c_1 c_2 

do
  echo "Name : $c_1"
  echo "Age : $c_2"
   
if [ $c_2 == "18" ]
then
    echo "$c_1 can drive"
fi

done < <(tail -n +2 teste_input.csv)
```

After I run my code, I get :

```
Name : Marc
Age : 18
Name : Joseph
Age : 10
```

I was expecting:

```
Name : Marc
Age : 18
Marc can drive
Name : Joseph
Age : 10
```

I already tried a lot of stuff without success. I can use `c_1` and `c_2` as input to some functions with no problem. The problem is just when I try to do math operations.

If I do:

```
s=$c_2+1
d=$((${c_2}+1))
```

it returns :

```
+1
+1")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

Same problem using  `d=$(("${c_2}+1"))`.

What should I change to make it run? Using `#!/bin/ksh`, `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` gives me the same results.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: this is not "bash code".  it's a `ksh` script, as is evident from the `#!/bin/ksh` line.

Comment: There is a lot of different between ksh, bh and bash? I have the same problem using which one of them.

Comment: Yes, there are differences (especially between `sh` and the other two) but that's not the issue here. Also, the shebang (`#!/bin/ksh`) is only half the story. How do you run the script? Do you call it directly (`path/to/script.sh`) or do you call it with a specific shell (e.g. `sh /path/to/script.sh`)?

Comment: Also, in the script you are running, `echo '$c_1 can drive'` is probably `echo "$c_1 can drive"` (double quotes), otherwise it would print `$c_1 can drive` (literally). Is this correct?

Comment: That said, you likely have Windows-style newline sequences (CR+LF) in your input file. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79702/315749 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32001/315749.

Comment: @terdon  i call as 'bash script.sh' inside the directorie. Its give me ' path/ bash script.sh'

Comment: @fra-san you right, its "$c_1 can drive".

Comment: OK, if you run it as `bash script.sh`, then the shebang (the first line, e.g. `#!/bin/ksh`) is irrelevant: the script will be run by `bash`. The shebang only works if you just run the script directly (`./script.sh`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are using a Windows text file. Your csv has Windows style line endings (`\r\n`). You can fix that using:

```
dos2unix teste_input.csv
```

Or if you don't have `dos2unix` installed, just do:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' teste_input.csv
```

That will make your code produce the output you are expecting. Almost:

```
$ foo.sh teste_input.fixed.csv 
Name : Marc
Age : 18
$c_1 can drive
Name : Joseph
Age : 10
```

The `$c_1` there is because of the single quotes in this line:

```
echo '$c_1 can drive'
```

Variables are not expanded inside single quotes so that's why you see `$c_1` and not the variable's value. You need:

```
echo "$c_1 can drive"
```

The next issue is that `==` is for string comparison and not arithmetic. It will work here, but if you want to compare numerical values, you want `-eq`:

```
if [ $c_2 -eq "18" ]
```

However, based on your "can drive" output, I suspect you want to check if the variable's value is equal to or greater than `18`, so you would use `-ge`:

```
 if [ $c_2 -ge "18" ]
```

Finally, you need to pick one shell to use. `ksh` is not the same as `bash` which is not the same as `sh`. While they have extremely similar syntax, it isn't identical and some things will work differently depending on what you use. For instance, `sh` doesn't support `<(command)`.

As for the arithmetic you tried, you just need to get the syntax right, you need to use an "arithmetic context". `s=$c_2+1` is just doing a simple variable assignment. It is setting the value of the variable `$s` to the the value of `$c_2` with the *string* `+1` added:

```
$ c_2=10
$ s=$c_2+1
$ echo "$s"
10+1
```

Your second example, `d=$((${c_2}+1))` does work, because `(( ))` sets an arithmetic context:

```
$ c_2=10
$ d=$((${c_2}+1))
$ echo "$d"
11
```

You got the syntax error because of the Windows line endings:

```
$ c_2=10$'\r'
$ d=$((${c_2}+1))
+1")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

So that will go away if you fix the file as I described in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Also, Bash arithmetic expansion knows that non-numeric terms are variables: `$(( c_2 + 1 ))` will work.