# find: missing argument to `-exec error

Tags: shell, find, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a couple of commands that allow me to create a .tar archive and then extract the files from it.

I am using WSL and both commands work just fine if I enter them directly, but not if I run them as a .sh file - I get the find: missing argument to `-exec' error.

To create the .tar, I have:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -exec tar cvf {}.tar {} \;
```

And to extract files I have:

```
find . -name "*.tar" -exec tar xf {} \;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please [check if you have maybe windows line endings in your .sh files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79702/how-to-test-whether-a-file-uses-crlf-or-lf-without-modifying-it) and if so, use `dos2unix` to convert them to unix line endings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info - running dos2unix on the .sh file (thanks for the tip!) has fixed this.

Thanks ever so much!

Comment: Creating a `tar` archive of a single file is pointless; you are only adding overhead,

Comment: Hi triplee, thanks for the comments. I'm creating a tar archive of directories containing thousands, sometimes tens of thousand of files. Thanks for the link, it's interesting reading. @pLumo gave me the fix for my problem.

Comment: @jim_e_jib Great that this fixed the issue. Next time, you can create your files directly with Linux Line Endings, any proper Editor should be able to do that, e.g. [see here for notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195839/choose-newline-character-in-notepad).

Comment: I can't see a thumbs up option for comments - thanks for the tip, I didn't realised notepad++ could do that :-)